# How to do the same thing with Array and ArrayList?

Tags: java

So, I have an OOP course and my assignment was to make an abstract employee class and than make further base classes for it. This part was easy and after that I had to make an array of objects of 'Employee' type and use the whole polymorphism thing to initiate all the base classes accordingly.

This is the code I wrote in my main:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int Size;
    System.out.println("Enter Array Size");
    Size = input.nextInt();

    Employee [] Array = new Employee [Size];

    int i;
    int A;

    System.out.println("Key: ");
    System.out.println("Press 1 for Salaried Employee.");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for Hourly Employee.");
    System.out.println("Press 3 for Commision Employee.");
    System.out.println("Press 4 for Base Plus Commision Employee.");


    String Name;
    String SSN;
    double wage;
    double hours;
    double salary;
    int Sales;
    double CRate;
    double BaseSalary;

    for (i = 0; i < Array.length; i++ ) {
        A = input.nextInt();
        if (A == 1) {

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Name");
                input.nextLine();
                Name = input.nextLine();
            } while (Name == "");

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Social Security Number");
                SSN = input.nextLine();
            } while (SSN == "");

            Array [i] = new Salaried_Employee(Name, SSN);

            System.out.println("Initial Earnings!" +Array[i].Earnings());


        }
        if (A == 2) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Name");
                input.nextLine();
                Name = input.nextLine();
            } while (Name == "");

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Social Security Number");
                SSN = input.nextLine();
            } while (SSN == "");

            System.out.println("Enter Wage!");
            wage = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Enter hours!");
            hours = input.nextDouble();

            Array [i] = new Hourly_Employee (Name, SSN, wage, hours);
        }

        if (A == 3) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Name");
                input.nextLine();
                Name = input.nextLine();
            } while (Name == "");

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Social Security Number");
                SSN = input.nextLine();
            } while (SSN == "");

            System.out.println("Enter Sales!");
            Sales = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter Commision Rate!");
            CRate = input.nextDouble();

            Array [i] = new Comission_Employee (Name, SSN, Sales, CRate);
        }

        if (A == 4) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Name");
                input.nextLine();
                Name = input.nextLine();
            } while (Name == "");

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Social Security Number");
                SSN = input.nextLine();
            } while (SSN == "");

            System.out.println("Enter Sales!");
            Sales = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter Commision Rate!");
            CRate = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Define the base salary");
            BaseSalary = input.nextDouble();

            Array [i] = new BassPlus_CommEmployee (Name, SSN, Sales, CRate, BaseSalary);
        }
    }
```

Now I have to do the exact same thing through Array List. I have googled the life out of this issue but I do not get how I can make an ArrayList that is of Employee type.

Please, Help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

EDIT:

```
employeeList.add(new BassPlus_CommEmployee (Name, SSN, Sales, CRate, BaseSalary));
employeeList.add(new Hourly_Employee (Name, SSN, wage, hours));
```

etc.

I assume Employee is the `Superclass`. Well I think it is since you are using this exact snippet in your code.

Comment: I tried that but the thing is if I do employeelist.add() how will I make sure its referring to which class since employee is only the abstract class

Comment: With Java7 and higher you won't even ned the `<Employee>` on the right side, so `List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();` will work as well.

Comment: you can add any subclass of `Employee` to this array

Comment: @RSkyler It is pretty much the same as you used it before in your code. I edited the answer with a example.

Comment: @RSkyler No problem. Mark this answer as helpful and have fun at trying out stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is an `Object` that contains other `Object`.
So you'll have to call methods to replace the assignement you did with `Array`.

`array[i] = new Employee();` can be transposed to `arraylist.add(new Employee())` for example

Then you'll need to find how to `get` the value to transpose `Employee e = array[i]`

Don't forget not to work with a null `ArrayList`.